# MongoDB with Node.js PUT problems

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I am working through the Developing Backbone.js Applications and I am trying to set up example2 which involves installing node.us with npm and Mongodb.
All seems to be installed properly, I can do some poking around mongodb with the mongo console, node.js is running fine, got my example server running and (seemingly) no errors on connecting to the mongodb:

```
//Connect to database
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/library_database', function(err) { if (err)
console.log(err); } );
```

No errors... but on an attempt to post:

```
jQuery.post( '/api/books', {
    'title': 'JavaScript the good parts',
    'author': 'Douglas Crockford',
    'releaseDate': new Date( 2008, 4, 1 ).getTime()
}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log( 'Post response:' );
    console.dir( data );
    console.log( textStatus );
    console.dir( jqXHR );
});
```

I'm getting a server 500 errors... no indication from the console or DB that anything was even attempted.

The get works fine, though there's nothing in the database, it comes back empty, but I can't get the post to work.

Can anyone suggest a process for debugging this? Is it possible my DB is configured read only?

Comment: Can you show how a request with the path `'/api/books'` is handled by your node.js app?

Comment: [As shown in the book](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#connect-to-the-database)

Comment: Well, I was hoping to avoid reading that book to understand your problem. In any case, I did read up to the point where you implement the route and the xhr request. I didn't see where the author explains how to install and start the `mongod` service. This must be done outside of installing the mongodb node module. Have you setup the `mongod` service correctly?

Comment: @JoshC.  well, I'm running mongo as described by the installation instructions from their web site, but I'm not running it as a service. I'm simply running it from the console. Should this make a difference?

Comment: To add, no special installation instructions were provided by this text, just to install it from mongo.

Comment: Are you on linux, windows, mac???

Comment: So, with `mongod` running, are you able to query using `mongo`?

Comment: this is on a windows 8 system.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to use the edit rules in this blasted editor...

Yes.. I can issues commands across to the database from the mongo console as recommended in the installation steps:

C:\Users\Karl>C:\mongodb\bin\mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
> db.test.save( { a: 1 } )
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5312922763e1da64a45989e4"), "a" : 1 }

Comment: Is the request making it to your route code? Log the request immediately once it enters the function

Comment: So it turns out order makes a difference when defining the server.js
Not enough just just to put the instructions in the file, but it has to flow top down properly. The instructions in the book don't really mention this, but after comparing to the source on github and adjusting, it's working. Sorry for the wasted bandwidth and your attempts to help me Josh.